# Laravel 5 | Session Flash For Form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I just finished setting up a form that takes some data and does a quick validation to confirm everything selected. On the confirm page, there's an (submit button) action method that calls the controller to store the data. The problem is, when I click submit the next page is just blank. I have debugbar enabled but nothing pops up at all to give me some insight, it's just a blank page.

Do I have to use a different flash call?

Heres my 'QuoteRequestController.php'

```
 public function confirm(Requests\PrepareQuoteRequest $request, Guard $auth)
     {
        $quotetemplate = $this->compileQuoteRequestTemplate($data = $request->all(), $auth);

        session()->flash('quote', $data);

        return view('quotes.confirm', compact('quotetemplate'));

        $request->get('$datacenters');


    }

public function store ()
 {

    $data = session()->get('quote');

    return $data;

    }
```

Update:

After doing some recon it seems that this White Screen of Death is probably because of a "return" issue. Playing around with redirect to see what happens

Comment: What do you have in the view you're returning?

Comment: Hi Dallin, no view is being passed to it, as soon as the store method is processed I just want it to spit out the raw json of the form

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a view before you try and get data from the session in your controller. `session()->flash()` should only last for one request. Try using `session()->put()` instead

Comment: Same result - i wasn't sure if the order of which the statements affected the logic processing so I moved stuff around but still no luck =/

Comment: Well that's all I got with the code provided. `$request->get('$datacenters');` isn't being called because you're return something before but I'm not sure what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the return in the controller

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the `session->Flash()` method wasn't working, so i switched both over to `session::put('quote', $request->all());` & `Session::pull('quote');`

Comment: I had the problem, then I realized I had my Chrome DevTools F12 (with disable cache) open! Arghhh